# How to perform calculations to properties of a javascript object and print it out

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am still learning javascript and this is **NOT** a homework problem.
I have an object collection

```
var x = [{name:'Ann',age:1,ending:'years old'},  
{name:'Bob',age:2,ending:'years old'},  
{name:'Cat',age:3,ending:'years old'},  
{name:'Dog',age:10,ending:'years old'},  
{name:'Fly',age:5,ending:'years old'}]
```

I want to know how to:
1, perform calculations to **all** 'age', such as age = age+1
2, put calculated data into object collection // x.push(age) I guess?
3, print out 'x' in this way:

```
    console.log(x[name]+' is '+x[age]+''+x[ending]+[calculations to age])
    //Ann is 1 years old2
    //Bob is 2 years old3....
```

I know the sentence doesn't make sense, but it doesn't matter.

My try:

```
var arr = '';

for (var property in x){
arr += x[property]+'\t';
}

var newArr = arr.split('\t')
,calculatedData = newArr[1]+1 ;
newArr.push(calculatedData) ;  
console.log(newArr[0]+' is '+newArr[1]+''+newArr[2]+calculatedData );
```

Comment: `for i in x { x[i].age++; }`?

Comment: Your values for your name key aren't strings which will throw an error thinking they are undefined variables.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e0qdbb13/

Comment: Side note: Your various names probably need to be in quotes, e.g. `name:"Ann"` rather than `name:Ann` (unless you happen to have a variable called `Ann`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I'll change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1, perform calculations to all 'age', such as age = age+1

What you're doing there is *looping through an array*. There are lots of ways to do that in JavaScript; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for a long list. In modern JavaScript, `forEach` is common:

```
x.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.age = entry.age + 1;
    // more commonly written like this:
    // ++entry.age;
});
```

Note how each array entry is given to our callback function as the first argument.

Or alternately, the venerable old `for` loop:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < x.length; ++index) {
    x[index].age = x[index].age + 1;
    // more commonly:
    // ++x[index].age;
}
```

Note how we have to look up the entry by index, `x[index]`.

> 2, put calculated data into object collection // x.push(age) I guess?

Well, if we update `age` on the objects, it's already there. Alternately, we could create a *new* array with the results using `map`:

```
var newArray = x.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.age + 1;
});
```

Now, `newArray` is an array of numbers, the result of adding 1 to each age.

But based on your question #3, more likely you want to add a new property with the updated age:

```
x.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.updatedAge = entry.age + 1;
});
```

> 3, print out 'x' in this way:

That's another loop:

```
x.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.name + " is " + entry.age + " " + entry.ending + " " + entry.updatedAge);
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var x = [{name:"Ann",age:1,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Bob",age:2,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Cat",age:3,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Dog",age:10,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Fly",age:5,ending:'years old'}];

x.forEach(function(entry) {
  entry.updatedAge = entry.age + 1;
});

x.forEach(function(entry) {
  snippet.log(entry.name + " is " + entry.age + " " + entry.ending + " " + entry.updatedAge);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

You can, of course, do it all in *one* loop:

```
x.forEach(function(entry) {
  snippet.log(entry.name + " is " + entry.age + " " + entry.ending + " " + (entry.age + 1));
  // Note the () ----------------------------------------------------------^-------------^
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var x = [{name:"Ann",age:1,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Bob",age:2,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Cat",age:3,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Dog",age:10,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Fly",age:5,ending:'years old'}];

x.forEach(function(entry) {
  snippet.log(entry.name + " is " + entry.age + " " + entry.ending + " " + (entry.age + 1));
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the collection and perform you calculation per each iteration:

```js
var x = [{name:"Ann",age:1,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Bob",age:2,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Cat",age:3,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Dog",age:10,ending:'years old'},  
{name:"Fly",age:5,ending:'years old'}];

for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
   //perform calc on age
   x[i].age = x[i].age + 1;
   //print info in object
   console.log(x[i].name+' is '+x[i].age+' '+x[i].ending); 
}
```